# Can I debug an Exe

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, disassembly

I need to compare few function calls and signature between my application and an working application. Here I don't mean any way to reverse engineer or access the source code of the other application , but truly need to know what are the methods , Interfaces used by the working application.

I tried attaching my application to Visual Studio and then , `Start>Debug` , but this doesn't provide any useful information. Any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Reflector Pro](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/walkthrough_getting_started.htm) Visual Studio plug in can debug not only exe you write, but any other assembly ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can debug code, but once its compiled, its machine language and a debugger in Visual Studio is not going to do anything at all.

In order to get an idea of what a compiled executable is doing, you can use a program like this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Runtime Flow](http://www.svprogramming.net/runtime-flow/index.html) (developed by me) can show all method calls in the working .NET application without need for source code.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of solutions that I can think of:

1. Attach the exe with VS IDE Debugger, and use [PDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241903.aspx) files to debug the exe
2. Use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to point towards your exe, and check the source. [See example](http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2006/08/01/ReflectorAddInLivesAgain.aspx).

Comment: Where is the Debug Store Located

Comment: @Subhen: What do you mean by *Debug Store*? PDB files gets generated when you build a project, usually in `debug` folder, depending upon the settings you have.

Comment: After Compiling the Code it ,I is not displaying the code in Visual Studio. I am using VS Plugin. After Compiling the code it says "Saving Decompiled assembly to Debug Store".

Comment: @Subhen: Checkout `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Red Gate\.NET Reflector 6\Cache`?